Table transformation in Excel file
I have an Excel file where I occasionally enter new information.
and this information looks like this:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6
Column7
Column8
Column9




1
Воробій Сергій Михайлович
Підволочиський районний суд Тернопільської області
51-6905 км 23
Бородій Василь Миколайович
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

19.02.2024




ч. 2 ст.   286-1



Мазур Микола Вікторович

14.00



2
Колодочка Анна Сергіївна
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-1713 км 20
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

24.01.2024




ч.5 ст.   185



Чистик Андрій Олегович

Жов.30










19.02.2024










Гру.30



3
Гуреєв Максим Олександрович
Слов'янський міськрайонний суд Донецької області
51-2299 км 23
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   14, ч. 3 ст. 27, п.п. 11, 12 ч. 2 ст. 115



Чистик Андрій Олегович

12.00



4
Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької   області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

15.11.2023




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365



Ковтунович Микола Іванович

Жов.30




Франковський   Роман Станіславович





19.02.2024




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365





15.30



5
Макоцей Сергій Григорович
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-5803 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

31.01.2024








Ковтунович   Микола Іванович

Жов.30










19.02.2024










15.15



6
Юдін Дмитро Леонідович
Глобинський районний суд Полтавської області
51-1811 км 23
Ковтунович Микола Іванович
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

17.01.2024




ч. 2 ст.   286-1, ч. 3 ст. 135, ст. 70



Фомін Сергій Борисович

11.00










19.02.2024










12.00



7
Денисенко Тетяна Дмитрівна
Шевченківський районний суд міста Києва
51-5417 зр 23
Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович
Марчук Олександр Петрович

19.02.2024








Яковлєва Світлана Володимирівна

Вер.30




Денисенко   Анатолій Дмитрович





















Зяхор   Михайло Федорович









8
Раку Олександр Андрійович
Октябрський районний суд м. Полтави
51-4973 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   286, ст. 46



Луганський Юрій Миколайович

15.00



9
Дмитришин Сергій Миколайович
Малиновський районний суд м. Одеси
51-5128 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76



Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

14.00




Хоменський   Олександр Миколайович










ч. 1 ст.   14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76










Коваль   Євгеній Євгенійович










ч. 4 ст.   187, ст. 69, ст. 75, ст. 76









10
Анисімов Володимир Олегович
Оболонський районний суд міста Києва
51-6505 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   309



Луганський Юрій Миколайович

15.00



11
Фролов Денис Валерійович
Заводський районний суд м. Запоріжжя
51-4991 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

17.01.2024




ч. 4 ст.   408, ст. 69



Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

13.00




Дригайло   Тарас Вячеславович





19.02.2024










13.20















Where I have rows with number 1,2,3... etc.
And I need take only first row and change table to this(example):



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6
Column7
Column8
Column9




1
Воробій Сергій Михайлович
Підволочиський районний суд Тернопільської області
51-6905 км 23
Бородій Василь Миколайович
ч. 2 ст.   286-1

19.02.2024



2
Колодочка Анна Сергіївна
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-1713 км 20
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч.5 ст.   185

24.01.2024



3
Гуреєв Максим Олександрович
Слов'янський міськрайонний суд Донецької області
51-2299 км 23
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч. 1 ст.   14, ч. 3 ст. 27, п.п. 11, 12 ч. 2 ст. 115

19.02.2024



4
Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької   області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365

15.11.2023



5
Макоцей Сергій Григорович
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-5803 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович


31.01.2024



6
Юдін Дмитро Леонідович
Глобинський районний суд Полтавської області
51-1811 км 23
Ковтунович Микола Іванович
ч. 2 ст.   286-1, ч. 3 ст. 135, ст. 70

17.01.2024



7
Денисенко Тетяна Дмитрівна
Шевченківський районний суд міста Києва
51-5417 зр 23
Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович


19.02.2024



8
Раку Олександр Андрійович
Октябрський районний суд м. Полтави
51-4973 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст.   286, ст. 46

19.02.2024



9
Дмитришин Сергій Миколайович
Малиновський районний суд м. Одеси
51-5128 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст.   14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76

19.02.2024




I created queries, but if I have under number for example 1 several people:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6
Column7
Column8
Column9




4
Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

15.11.2023




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365



Ковтунович Микола Іванович

Жов.30




Франковський   Роман Станіславович





19.02.2024




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365





15.30




to this:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6
Column7
Column8
Column9




4
Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365

15.11.2023





This formula seems to work in my sheet. In order to understand what you want to do i've replaced some of your data in my sheet. Perhaps you have to change "TT.MM.JJJ" according to your regional settings.
=LET(filldown,SCAN("",A2:A33,LAMBDA(ini,arr,IF(arr<>"",arr,ini))),
DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(filldown),LAMBDA(u,v,
VSTACK(u,
HSTACK(
INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),1,SEQUENCE(,5)),
IF(INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),2,2)=0, 
{""},INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),2,2)),{""},
TEXT(INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),1,8),"TT.MM.JJJ"),
{""}))))
,1)
)



but if has value changes (number of rows)

then change A2:A33 to e.g. A2:A200 and A2:I33 accordingly to A2:I200

Hello! If you remember, maaybe you can help me again, i need take second date from table, and i dont know how :(
